# Integrate API in SignUp Policy for validating User Input

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have an existing API deployed to Azure Portal.

For Ex: https://Edudev.azure-api.net/validate?param1=value

API response is a JSON object,
For Ex:

{
"Message": "Please provide details\r\n",

"NeedInfo": "true"

}

we need to pass subscription key in the header whenever we call this api

My Question is:

Can I call this api in SignUp Policy Xml in Azure AD B2C user journey as validation of user input and display the message returned in response

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

A REST API can be invoked from a custom policy as described at "[Integrate REST API claims exchanges in your Azure AD B2C user journey as validation of user input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw)".

You can secure the REST API using either [HTTP basic authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw-secure-basic) or [client certificate authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw-secure-cert).

You can otherwise pass the subscription key in the request query string.

An input claim, such as `param1`, can be passed in:

- The request query string
- The request headers
- The request body as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- The request body as `application/json`

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>REST APIs</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-Validate">
      <DisplayName>Validate REST API</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://edudev.azure-api.net/validate?subscription-key=...</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None|Basic|ClientCertificate</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body|Form|Header|QueryString</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="param1" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        ...
      </OutputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

[The REST API must return a `409 Conflict` response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-validation-custom#step-1-prepare-the-rest-api-function) in order for messages to be shown to users:

```
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "status": 409,
  "userMessage": "Please provide details."
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I got a 404 error when I use subscription key in the querystring. Is there any way I can pass the input parameter in the querystring and the subscription key in the header

Comment: hi did you find solution? I have run into similar error, where querystring doesnt work